# Why is there extra space at the bottom of this plot?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, bar-chart

I just created a horizontal stacked bar chart using matplotlib, and I can't figure out why there is extra space between the x axis and the first bar (code and picture below). Any suggestions or questions? Thanks!

Code:

```
fig = figure(facecolor="white")
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg="white")
heights = .43
data = np.array([source['loan1'],source['loan2'],source['loan3']])
dat2 = np.array(source2)
ind=np.arange(N)
left = np.vstack((np.zeros((data.shape[1],), dtype=data.dtype), np.cumsum(data, axis=0) [:-1]))
colors = ( '#27A545', '#7D3CBD', '#C72121')

for dat, col, lefts, pname2 in zip(data, colors, left, pname):
    ax1.barh(ind+(heights/2), dat, color=col, left=lefts, height = heights, align='center', alpha = .5)

p4 = ax1.barh(ind-(heights/2), dat2, height=heights, color = "#C6C6C6", align='center', alpha = .7)

ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
yticks([z for z in range(N)], namelist)

#mostly for the legend
params = {'legend.fontsize': 8}
rcParams.update(params)
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1, box.width, box.height * 0.9])
l = ax1.legend(loc = 'upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.05), fancybox=True, shadow = True, ncol = 4)

show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because matplotlib tries to intelligently choose minimum and maximum limits for the plot (i.e. "round-ish" numbers) by default.

This makes a lot of sense for some plots, but not for others.

To disable it, just do `ax.axis('tight')` to snap the data limits to the strict extents of the data.

If you want a bit of padding despite the "tight" bounds on the axes limits, use `ax.margins`.

In your case, you'd probably want something like:

```
# 5% padding on the y-axis and none on the x-axis
ax.margins(0, 0.05)

# Snap to data limits (with padding specified above)
ax.axis('tight')
```

Also, if you want to set the extents manually, you can just do

```
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])`
```

or use `set_xlim`, `set_ylim`, or even

```
ax.set(xlim=[xmin, xmax], ylim=[ymin, ymax], title='blah', xlabel='etc')
```

Comment: Ah such a simple fix. I had seen that specification around, but apparently forgot about it it when the appropriate time came. Thank you!